# Static lib linking error: Symbols not found for architecture

Tags: ios, xcode, libraries, static-linking

I need to link FFMPEG's libraries (libavformat, libavcodec, etc) to my project.
I have downloaded as an example iFrameExtractor project, and have successfully build it.

xcode-proj opens fine and the sample app works fine, so I just took libs from this project to my one.
But xcode fails to build it, saying me

```
  Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "av_register_all()", referenced from:
```

I checked target settings, and I cannot see any difference between my project's settings and iFrameExtractor. 
I just moved all ffmpeg folder to my project's folder.

Notes:

1) nm commands tells me that this symbol is inside the library.

2) library is fat-file, including i386, armv6, armv7 architectures.

Please, help me, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I just went through this yesterday :-)

In xcode, you need to add the .a file to the list of linked libraries in the project. The easiest way to do that is by dragging the .a directly onto the project entry in the navigation area on the left:

[image: adding libraries via drag and drop.]

Alternatively, you can select them from the dialogs in the summary area of the project editor:

[image: adding libraries via selection]

Just make sure you select the actual .a files, not the whole folder. Then, simply import their headers (as you are likely already doing...), and you should be good to go :-)